SQLAlchemy select in aiogram 3
I'm making a bot for telegram with aiogram and sqla. Got a database and now i want to select attribute "name" from a table.
async def orm_get_name(session: AsyncSession, tg_id: int) -> str:
    query = select(User.name).where(User.tg_id==tg_id)
    result = await session.execute(query)
    return result

The function works in other file:
@user_private_router.message(StateFilter(None), CommandStart())
async def start_handler(message: types.Message, session: AsyncSession, state: FSMContext):
    if await set_user(session, message.from_user.id) == True:
        await message.answer(("Hello " + str(await orm_get_name(session, message.from_user.id)) + "!"),       reply_markup=reply.start_kb)
    else: ......

I have correct data in database but the bot doesn't write name, it writes memory address:
"Hello <sqlalchemy.engine.result.ChunkedIteratorResult object at 0x0000017886C0FE50>!"
How can I fix it? Didn't find answer in documentary.
2024-05-14 14:23:54,450 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-05-14 14:23:54,452 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine PRAGMA main.table_info("users")
2024-05-14 14:23:54,452 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2024-05-14 14:23:54,456 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine PRAGMA main.table_info("groups")
2024-05-14 14:23:54,457 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2024-05-14 14:23:54,460 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine PRAGMA main.table_info("task")
2024-05-14 14:23:54,461 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2024-05-14 14:23:54,464 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2024-05-14 14:23:56,671 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-05-14 14:23:56,687 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT users.id, users.tg_id, users.name,        users.created, users.updated 

FROM users
WHERE users.tg_id = ?
2024-05-14 14:23:56,687 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00151s] (1989405912,)
2024-05-14 14:23:56,694 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT users.name
FROM users
WHERE users.tg_id = ?
2024-05-14 14:23:56,695 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00101s] (1989405912,)
2024-05-14 14:23:56,947 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
I'm expecting the answer from bot like this one:
"Hello John!"

return result[0]

UPD:
I had to add scalar() in  "return result"
Thus,
return result.scalar()

